# Using same array in multiple python modules

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and programming. I have tried searching for this, but have not been able to find an answer.

I am looking for best way to take a data file append it to an array, and use it in multiple python modules. As a 1. semester science student, I know I will be using this many times during my education, so I would like some help, to find a better way to do this.

Here is an example from my first semester Group project. Where we were asked to simulate a speaker using python to help as with different tasks. We were given impedans reading to use in a data file. The data file has 3 collumns. Frequenzy, real impedance, imaginary impedance.

In the first file lets call it import_define.py . We have the following code, importing from the datafile called data.

```
infile = open('data.dat', 'r')
infile.readline()

freq_list = []
real_list = []
imag_list = []

for line in infile:
    split = line.split()
    freq_list.append(float(split[0][:-1]))
    real_list.append(float(split[1][:-1]))
    imag_list.append(float(split[2]))
infile.close()

import numpy as np

freqenzy = np.asarray(freq_list)
real_imp = np.asarray(real_list)
imag_imp = np.asarray(imag_list)
```

Then we have used the three arrays for different calculations within this module.

Now we want to use these arrays in a different module plot.py, where we want to plot some data from these 3 arrays, and from different data calculated in import_define.py

What we have done is to define 3 functions in import_define.py that return the arrays, like so:

```
def freq_func():
    return frequenzy

def real_imp_func():
    return real_imp

def imag_imp_func():
    return imag_imp
```

In the file plot.py, we did the following to import and use the arrays in this new module:

```
import import_define as imd

freq = imd.freq_func()
real = imd.real_imp_func()
imag = imd.imag_imp_func()
```

So what I would like to ask if there is a better or more correct way to do this, when using python.

Comment: You don't need the 3 functions you already imported the module so you can access `freqenzy`, `real_imp` and `imag_imp`.

Answer (score 1):

The array variables are globals in import_define module, so you can use them directly:

```
import import_define as imd
print imd.frequenzy
```

I think you can use `numpy.loadtxt` to load the array from file quickly, without for loop.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that the variables could be imported and used as well.

I tried to use numpy.loadtxt with the data file,but it did not work because the file uses 2 different delimeters. Comma and colon.

Here are a few sample lines from the data file:

    'Freq [Hz]   Z_in (real) Z_in (imag.)
    10.00000010: 6.08147910, 2.55728010
    10.19990010: 6.08487810, 2.60997610
    10.39980010: 6.08835310, 2.66276710'

How can I use, numpy.loadtxt with this file

Answer (score 0):

No need to have those functions. From within the plot.py, you can access those variables with:

```
import import_define as id

id.freqenzy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the singleton pattern.

```
class ModuleSharedFile:

    class __SharedFile:
        def __init__(self, file_path):
            self.file_path = file_path
            self.array = self.__loadArray()
        def __str__(self):
            return repr(self) + self.val
        def __loadArray(self):
            # Do your stuff here.
            pass

    instance = None

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        if not ModuleSharedFile.instance:
            ModuleSharedFile.instance = ModuleSharedFile.__SharedFile(file_path)
        else:
            ModuleSharedFile.instance.file_path = file_path

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
```

Then where ever you create an instance of ModuleSharedFile, you will be working with the same file/array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is described in: "How do I share global variables across modules?": http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.htm

> Because there is only one instance of each module, any changes made to the module object get reflected everywhere.

So instances of python modules are singletons.

You create empty file `dummy.py`, which gets initialized as a module.

```
# module1.py
import dummy
dummy.x = "value"  # set shared value

# module2.py
import dummy
print dummy.x      # read shared value
```